# How to test the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{n\log(n)}\right)^{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I genuinely can't seem to understand which test to apply here, I tried root test, I cant seem to show its converging, please any hint is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try the ratio test perhaps?

Comment: $a_n=\left( \frac{2}{n\log n}\right)^{2^n}$ so $|a_n|^{1/n}\to 0.$

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/721644).

Comment: If you don't know how to solve a problem even after revising the theory and analyzing examples given to you, try to search the web first. One efficient engine is the [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/). More often, you can find the same question already existing, but if not, why not clicking a related one and see what you can work out from it? If you were told a series converges, you can try to find a convergent series whose terms are greater by the absolute value or something. If you know two convergent series, you might want to apply sth like the squeeze theorem.

Comment: If you tried the root test, show us your _try_. If you don't know where to star from, you can at least list the theory you've been introduced to so as to help the community members give you better answers. Once you state what the problem is, it can be solved in one or two questions.

Comment: Searching first is the best option in these situations because there might have been people with same obstacles who had already been given hints. When you ask a question, make sure you take everything you can from it, by which I mean, just write down everything confusing.

Comment: Ok see, even this question, it's originally from another question where I figured it out pretty much on my own, let me share the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801373/does-the-sum-sum-n-2-infty-fracn-ln-leftn-right-lnn-leftn-rig   so here cauchy condesation test has been used which i figured it out, the place where i am always struggling is here they formed the inequality $n + n^2(logn)$ < $2^n$ when students encounter a question which i gave the link for, the student has to solve these kind of questions literally under 3 mins so they have to form this inequality on their own.

Comment: $n + n^2logn$ < $2^n$ so like WHERE are they getting this $2^n$ from? Are they simply looking at the denominator's power and forming that inequality? and even then its my own assumption. I could be completely wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $n \ge 3$,
$$\left( \frac{2}{n\log{n}} \right)^{2^n} \le \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^{2^n} \le \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2^n} \le \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n.$$
This easily gives convergence.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still TRYING to understand this concept of real analysis, its an extremely difficult topic that i have to cover for my exam and seeing these inequalities helps understand pattern to study series. I am utterly confused as to what you're mentioning as "refused to cooperate" as i have not been given "warning" to "attempt" question. I am NOT looking for final answer here, I came here to learn approaches

Comment: Last time i remember the only thing i was warned about was my coding for the mathematical notations

Comment: I am a graduate students, You have to understand, majority of students at this level are completely uninterested in reaching final answer in fact if you read my question, it says already its converging but i am not sure how to test it properly. reaching final answer means nothing to me, its all about the approaches that i learn

Comment: @Riri, you even deleted a question where I gave you a link to the same question already answered years prior. If you remember, other community members voted to close your question for the lack of context. I made a mistake and voted to close it as a duplicate. I'm sure you know what I'm talking about because there had already been two votes for closing this question before I voted. As a person who posted it, you can see it. The policy rules clearly state you have to **show your attempts**. I warned you about editing after others had done the same more than once.

Comment: I do NOT remember, especially if it happened years ago, and please kindly link me that question, if you want an apology for that, then here it is, I am sorry, however, i do NOT know how to form the inequality for series question, and in my class friends and tutors are not extensively teaching on how to develop the tactics of forming the inequalities, so i am learning approaches from the above post

Comment: I can't give you the link because it has been deleted. If it wasn't you, then it is justified, moreover the moderators probably considered it inappropriate if it was their decision to retain the high-quality of the site, which only confirms my statement. I' m a student just like you and we haven't had lectures for months due to the pandemic. Please, include your work, show us the step where you couldn't continue from and clarify what exactly you don't understand. _I can't seem to show it's converging_ doesn't mean you know it is so.

Comment: "I can't seem to show it's converging", doesn't mean you know it. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean those statements don't mean the same thing. You could've written: _I think/know it converges, but it don't know how to show it_ etc.

Answer (score 4):

*HINT*: for large enough $n$

$$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n}{2} \log(n) \right)^{2^n}} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$$